# send array with JSON

Tags: jquery, json

i'm using this code for post text of option tag :

```
$("#major_names").change(function () {
    $.post('find_lesson.php',  { dars:$("#major_names option:selected").text() },
        function(data){ 
            if (data.success)
                        $("div").append(data.doroos);
            else
                alert('mm');
        },'json'); 
return false; 
});
```

now in find_lesson file i use this code for fetch any record from database

```
<?php

$lessonName=$_POST['lesson '];
$query= mysql_query("SELECT * FROM at_*** WHERE title = '{$lessonName}'");
$result= mysql_fetch_array($query);

$sql= mysql_query("SELECT * FROM  *** JOIN at_lessons ON  . . .");
while($result=mysql_fetch_assoc($sql))
{
$data ['doroos']= $result['title'];
}
$data['success']=true;


echo json_encode($data);

?>
```

mysql command is correct but after send array i have getting 1 record. please help me

Answer (score 5):

Change

```
$data ['doroos']= $result['title'];
```

to

```
$data ['doroos'][] = $result['title'];
```

You are basically overwriting the `doroos`. Instead, use `[]` to add every `$result['title']` to `doroos`.

Comment: hello. after change it i getting this error in firebug : NS_ERROR_XPC_BAD_CONVERT_JS: Could not convert JavaScript argument arg 0 [nsIDOMDocumentFragment.appendChild]
[Break On This Error]  

fragment.appendChild( script );

Comment: It's a javascript error. do `alert(data.doroos)` and tell what you get.

Answer (score 0):

You should do something like below instead. Otherwise "doroos" will only have the last title record from the fetched resultset.

```
<?php

$lessonName=$_POST['lesson '];
$query= mysql_query("SELECT * FROM at_*** WHERE title = '{$lessonName}'");
$result= mysql_fetch_array($query);

$sql= mysql_query("SELECT * FROM  *** JOIN at_lessons ON  . . .");

$doroos = array();
$x = 0;
while($result=mysql_fetch_assoc($sql))
{    
     $doroos[x++] = $result['title'];
}
$data ['doroos']= $doroos;
$data['success']=true;


echo json_encode($data);

?>
```

Comment: i have get this error now: NS_ERROR_XPC_BAD_CONVERT_JS: Could not convert JavaScript argument arg 0 [nsIDOMDocumentFragment.appendChild]
[Break On This Error]  

fragment.appendChild( script );

jquery-latest.js (line 6497)

POST http://aou.ir/ivu/assessment/find_dars.php
 
200 OK
  35ms 
jquery-latest.js (line 8240)
HeadersPostResponseHTMLJSONCookies

{"doroos":[],"success":true}

Comment: after change code to this:

    $data['doroos'] = array();
    $x = 0;
    while($result=mysql_fetch_assoc($sql))
    {    
         $data['doroos'][$x++] = $result['title'];
    }
    $data['success']=true;
    echo json_encode($data);
    ?>
i can get this result in firebug:

    {"doroos":["\u0627\u0646\u0633\u0627\u0646 \u0634\u0646\u0627\u0633\u06cc"],"success":true}

but i can't show that with this line:

    if (data.success)
      $("div").append(data.doroos);